# Working with data objects vue-chartjs

Tags: chart.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

I am trying to populate a chart component dynamically with reference from a parent data object + mixins

Is there a way to pass a data Object to the methods eg. Labels to enumerate over my existing object of objects or do I have to build a custom solution to pass it an array?

eg

```
getDataLabels(){
  var array = [];
  for (var i=0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

edit: added tag